# How can i read SOAP body as one parameter in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

This is a sample request to a web service I'm working on:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
        <ns0:postRequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.mynamespace.com">
             <Firstname>Mike</Firstname>
             <Lastname>Adam</Lastname>
      </ns0:postRequest>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Currently I read each value as single parameter in the webmethod like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace myCode
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mynamespace.com")]
    public class testInt : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [SoapRpcMethod("http://www.mynamespace.com")]
        [WebMethod]
        public string postRequest(string Firstname, string Lastname)
        {
            return Lastname.ToString();

        }
    }


}
```

But in the real case there are much more parameters.
My question is how can read them as one parameter in the webmethod noting that I can't change the request XML format.

(By the way I created a class with Firstname and Lastname as properties in it and used this class as a parameter in the webmethod but it's always null)

Thanks much

Comment: Request body looks weird. As you sure it is numbering the requestid tags like that? If not for that the default model binder could possible parse it into a dto poco for you, but as it is you probably need a custom model binder.

Comment: well to make it more clear, I will change them to Firstname,Lastname @DanielvanHeerden

Comment: The problem is not with the numbering by itself. If all the tags had the same name. For example `<ValueItem>value1</ValueItem><ValueItem>value2</ValueItem>...` etc then you could have made a simple object with a string array called ValueItem and use that as parameter for your postRequest method, and the model binder would have bound it for you. You can create a object now with Firstname and Lastname and all your other properties in it, and the model binder will bind all the ones it finds to a new instance of your object and pass it into you postRequest method, but does that solve it for you?

Comment: Yes that will solve it for me..in fact this is what I want. I actually created a class that has firstname and lastname as properties and used it in the webmethod as a parameter but its always null...I'm not sure what the problem is and what is the proper code to solve this problem(if you have anything in mind we can do it on the sample code in my question) @DanielvanHeerden

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after. It shows you how to make an XML model binder. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/24/model-binding-xml-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

EDIT:
Something a little more pointed I just found is http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html which talks about a Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml nuget package. That is probably your best bet.